# using the same function of different events

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems pretty simple, but I can't figure it out. I'm new to javascript/ jquery.

i want to trigger a function to move a div onmouseover,  and another onmouseout. I want to call this same function on several different divs. how would I do this without writing multiple functions?

```
  <div id="indexJoinBanner" onmouseover="moveDivRight()" onmouseout="moveDivLeft()"> 
  <!-- end #indexJoinBanner --></div>
  <div id="indexJoinBanner2" onmouseover="moveDivRight()" onmouseout="moveDivLeft()"> 
  <!-- end #indexJoinBanner2 --></div>



function moveDivRight(){
  $("#indexJoinBanner").animate({
    left: "0px",
  },500 );
};

function moveDivLeft() {
  $("#indexJoinBanner").animate({
    left: "-150px",
  },500 );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Pass a parameter identifying the `div`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the div to the function like

```
<div id="indexJoinBanner" onmouseover="moveDivRight(this)" onmouseout="moveDivLeft(this)">
```

and use it in the function

```
function moveDivRight(div){
  $(div).animate({
    left: "0px",
  },500 );
};

function moveDivLeft(div) {
  $(div).animate({
    left: "-150px",
  },500 );
}
```

`this` in the attributes specify the current element.

Alternatively you can attach handler using `.on()` instead of onmouseover and onmouseout attributes, give all the elements you want to attach the handler a class then

```
$('.someclass').on('mouseover', function () {
  $(this).animate({
    left: "0px",
  },500 );
}).on('mouseout', function () {
  $(this).animate({
    left: "-150px",
  },500 );
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/qNBEJ/)

Comment: although I like the theory of your second method. I couldn't get it to work. However, your first approach works great. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#indexJoinBanner, #indexJoinBanner2").hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({left: '0px'}, 500);
},
function () {
    $(this).animate({left: '-150px'}, 500);
});
```

`.hover` allows you to bind mouseover and mouseout simultaneously, but you can also bind them separately.

You can use `this` to refer to the object that is the target of the binding (even if you bind to multiple elements at once).

You can also bind named functions if you want to.

**NOTE**: in this solution, the `onmouseover`, etc. attributes are not required in the HTML at all.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't accept this because I don't want to add a line to the function ever time I add another div. Still works good though. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "add a line to the function?"  Do you mean add to the selector?  Then don't use IDs.  Give every div that you want to have these animate properties a class and just bind to that class.

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="indexJoinBanner" onmouseover="moveDivRight()" onmouseout="moveDivLeft()"></div>
<div id="indexJoinBanner2" onmouseover="moveDivRight()" onmouseout="moveDivLeft()"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#indexJoinBanner').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({left: '0px'});
    });

    $('#indexJoinBanner2').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({left: '0px'});
    });

    $('#indexJoinBanner').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({left: '-150px'});
    });

    $('#indexJoinBanner2').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({left: '-150px'});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: oh look, multiple functions, _just like the OP didn't want!_